# Data is not populating in second level kartik depDrop in yii2. Gettin 0,1,2,3,4

Tags: yii2

When I'm selecting First Category - I can see the data in firebug that should populate in the secon level but it's instead populating 0,1,2,3,4 and I'm unable to select it.
My _form is

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\web\View;
use frontend\assets\XyzAsset;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use frontend\modules\production\models\Productbatch;
use frontend\modules\production\models\Productnames;
use kartik\depdrop\DepDrop;
use yii\helpers\Json;

//XyzAsset::register($this);
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\modules\production\models\Production */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="production-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <!--<?= Html::a('Select Product', ['/production/productbatch/index'], ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) ?> -->

    <?= $form->field($model, 'productiondate')->widget(
    DatePicker::className(), [
        // inline too, not bad
         'inline' => false, 
         // modify template for custom rendering
        //'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
        'clientOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        ]
    ]);?>

    <!-- echo CHtml::button("(+)",array('title'=>"Select Product",'onclick'=>'js:selectproductforproduction();')); -->   

    <?= $form->field($model, 'productname')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Productnames::find()->all(),'productnames_productname','productnames_productname'),
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Product Name', 'id' => 'cat-id'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'batchno')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
    'options'=>['id'=>'subcat-id'],
    'pluginOptions'=>[
        'depends'=>['cat-id'],
        'placeholder'=>'Select BatchNo',
        'url'=>Url::to(['/production/productbatch/subcat'])
    ]
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'prodqty')->textInput() ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Controller -

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\production\controllers;

use Yii;
use frontend\modules\production\models\Productbatch;
use frontend\modules\production\models\ProductbatchSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\helpers\Json;
/**
 * ProductbatchController implements the CRUD actions for Productbatch model.
 */
class ProductbatchController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Productbatch models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new ProductbatchSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Productbatch model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Productbatch model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Productbatch();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->itemid]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Productbatch model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->itemid]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Productbatch model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    public function actionSubcat() {
    $out = [];
    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
        $parents = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
        if ($parents != null) {
            $cat_id = $parents[0];
            $out = Productbatch::getBatchNo($cat_id);

            // the getSubCatList function will query the database based on the
            // cat_id and return an array like below:
            // [
            //    ['id'=>'<sub-cat-id-1>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name1>'],
            //    ['id'=>'<sub-cat_id_2>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name2>']
            // ]
            echo Json::encode(['output'=>$out, 'selected'=>'']);
            return;
        }
    }
    echo Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'selected'=>'']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Productbatch model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Productbatch the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Productbatch::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\production\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "productbatch".
 *
 * @property integer $itemid
 * @property string $productname
 * @property string $batchno
 * @property string $mfgdate
 * @property string $expdate
 * @property double $mrp
 * @property double $rate
 *
 * @property Productnames $productname0
 */
class Productbatch extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'productbatch';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['batchno'], 'string'],
            [['mfgdate', 'expdate'], 'safe'],
            [['mrp', 'rate'], 'number'],
            [['productname'], 'string', 'max' => 25]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'itemid' => 'Itemid',
            'productname' => 'Productname',
            'batchno' => 'Batchno',
            'mfgdate' => 'Mfgdate',
            'expdate' => 'Expdate',
            'mrp' => 'Mrp',
            'rate' => 'Rate',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getProductname0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Productnames::className(), ['productnames_productname' => 'productname']);
    }
    public static function getBatchNo($cat_id) 
    {
        $data = static::find()->where(['productname'=>$cat_id])->select(['batchno'])->asArray()->all();
        $value = (count($data) == 0) ? ['' => ''] : $data;

        return $value;
    }

}
```

The output looks like - 
[image]

Comment: try to change this line     'options'=>['id'=>'subcat-id'],
to     'options'=>[subcat-id'=>'subcat-id'],

Comment: Hi Sourav, this is not working.

Comment: im in hurry now need to go out,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZepxKw8VA7w watch this, this exactly what you need, if you still have issue post it i try to answer in evening

Comment: Hi Sourabh. This is very useful video. Thank you for your effort. I've found out the solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398502/yii2-using-kartik-depdrop-widget