# Yii2 dropdown2 selected depending on dropdown1

Tags: yii2, dropdown, selected

I have two standard dropdowns:

```
$form->field($model, 'typ_id')->dropDownList(
    \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Plra::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
);
```

and

```
$form->field($model, 'tol_id')->dropDownList(
    \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Plratol::find()->all(), 'id', 'name')
);
```

and I would like to make one certain value *selected* (virtually as a suggestion, as a default) in dropdown `tol_id` if one certain `typ_id` value is selected. Basically the two dropdowns are independent. As a workaround to achieve what I want, I can make it work as a dependent dropdown:

```
$form->field($model, 'typ_id')->dropDownList(
    \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Plra::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'), [
        'onchange' => '$.post("' . \Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('plra/listtol?typ_id=') . '"+$(this).val(), function(data) {$("select#tol_id").html(data);});',
    ]
);
```

and

```
$form->field($model, 'tol_id')->dropDownList(
    \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Plratol::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'), [
        'id' => 'tol_id'
    ]
);
```

Controller:

```
public function actionListtol($typ_id) {
    if ($typ_id == 2) {
        $plratol = Plratol::find()->where(['typ_id' => 2])->one();

        echo "<option value='" . $plratol->id . "'>" . $plratol->name . "</option>";
    } else {
        $plratols = Plratol::find()->where(['typ_id' => NULL])->all();

        echo "<option>Select</option>";
        foreach ($plratols as $plratol) {
            echo "<option value='" . $plratol->id . "'>" . $plratol->name . "</option>";
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm wondering is there a more simple way maybe mit `js` for such a simple dependency/scenario? If yes, can you please provide me sample code 'cause unfortunately js is not something I'm familiar with.

I would like to solve it without Kartik's DepDrop extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2: Using Kartik Depdrop Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398502/yii2-using-kartik-depdrop-widget)

Comment: I would like to solve it without extension. With dependent dropdown it's working.

Comment: if dependency between the dropdowns is made on serverside, you have to make an ajax request to handle your choice of the first dropdown, to dynamically generate the options of the second dropdown, or to choose one of them. While, if the dependency could be managed from clientside, use js to handle it on the change of the first dropdown. The implementation details is dependent on your business rules.

Comment: basically there is no dependency between the two dropdowns.

Comment: you have to provide us with a scenario, "if the user selected option X, the expected result should be Y..."

Comment: ok please add the code you have so far, also you are using select2 or normal dropdowns ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure javascript or jquery,

Add an `onchange()` event on 1st dropdown and using `ajax in onchange()` function get the required value of 2nd dropdown and set its html.

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't have any code to reference. If I understand correctly, your dependent dropdown won't work onload if you pass it a selected value. You can still get around this with JS.

```js
 $( document ).ready( function(){
        e = $('#parent'); // replace with your elements name
        e.change();
     });
```

The above code will trigger the `change` event and whatever value you have provided will be used in the dependent dropdown.